# Find number of pairs that add up to a specific number from two different lists?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sum, sum-of-digits

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b  = [56,59,62,65,67,69]


def sumOfTwo(a,b,v):
    for i in range (len(a)):
        val_needed = v - a[i]
        for j in range (len(b)):
            if b[j] == val_needed:
                x = b[j]
                y = a[i]             
    print(x,y) 

sumOfTwo(a,b,v=70)
```

Output: 5 65

What if more pairs are possible from the given lists in the problem, how do I do that?
Help.
What are more ways to achieve this?

Comment: Here you are printing out the **last** pair that matches. If you want to print **all** pairs that match, then you need the `print()` inside the `for` loops.

Comment: Thanks Code.Apprentice. You were quick. It takes O(n^2), can we reduce the time complexity?

Comment: That's a different question than what you originally asked. My first inclination is probably not. You might be able to reduce the constant factor if you know that both input lists are sorted. This will allow you to break as soon as the sum of two elements is larger than the target.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to print matched values, you just have to indent the print statement to be inside the`if`, as stated below. Also, you should use a more *pythonic* approach to `for` loops and also for variable assignments.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b  = [56,59,62,65,67,69]


def sumOfTwo(a,b,v):
    for i in a:
        val_needed = v - i
        for j in b:
            if j == val_needed:
                x, y = j, i
                print(x,y)

sumOfTwo(a,b,v=70)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b = [56,59,62,65,67,69]

c = [(x, y)
     for x in a
     for y in b
     if x + y == 70]

print(c)
```

This yields

```
[(1, 69), (3, 67), (5, 65)]
```